# Covariance between a random variable and an its corresponding indicator random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance

Let $X$ be a random variable from a uniform distribution $\mathrm{Unif}[1,2]$ and $U = h(X) = \begin{cases}1, & X < 5/4 \\ 0, & \mathrm{else}\end{cases}$

I want to find the covariance by using the expectation values of $X$, $U$ and $UX$.

I am having trouble finding the expectation value $\mathbb{E}[UX]$ since I'd have to calculate

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ux f_{UX}(u,x) \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}x$$

but I can't get the joint pdf. Since $u$ depends on $x$ in a deterministic way, does it even make sense to talk about a joint pdf?

On the other hand, the expectation values of $X$ and $U$ are pretty straight forward being $3/2$ (mean of uniform distribution) and $1/4$ (the probability that $X \leq 5/4)$ respectively.

Thank you

Comment: Observe that
$$
\mathbb{E}[XU] = \mathbb{E}[X \cdot \mathbf{1}[X < 5/4]] = \int_{-\infty}^{5/4}xf_X(x)dx
$$

Comment: So is it just getting the expected value of the variable $h(X)X$ with respect to the pdf of $X$ only?

Comment: @TheBosco, yes, because $U$ is totally dependent to $X$, in a sense that $|\text{cov}(U,X)|=\sqrt{\sigma^2_X\sigma^2_U}$.

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $UX$ does not admit a density as it has a positive probability mass in

$$\mathbb{P}[UX=0]=0.75$$

thus

$$\mathbb{E}[UX]=1.5\times0.25=0.375$$

concluding:

$$\mathbb{Cov}[U,X]=0.375-0.25\times1.5=0$$